# CommonDomain and NEventStore

Tags: domain-driven-design, cqrs, commondomain

I am currently using CommonDomain, and this works currently very well, but I have a few questions:

1. Is CommonDomain still being actively maintained? I see on GitHub that the last work was done around 2 years ago: https://github.com/joliver/CommonDomain
2. If it is being maintained is there any plan on upgrading CommonDomain to work with NEventStore 5?

Updating 'NEventStore 4.0.0.15' to 'NEventStore 5.0.1.2' failed. Unable to find a version of 'CommonDomain' that is compatible with 'NEventStore 5.0.1.2'.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CommonDomain is now being actively maintained as part of NEventStore:
https://github.com/NEventStore/NEventStore/tree/master/src/NEventStore/CommonDomain

Comment: Looks like the CommonDomain classes are being moved to NEventStore.Domain, https://github.com/NEventStore/NEventStore.Domain